# The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

To implement Exception Handling using Spring, I am trying to use @ControllerAdvice.
But it is giving compilation error.

**The import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice cannot be resolved**

I am using spring version **3.0.5.RELEASE**.

**ApplicationConext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**Java Class:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView exception(Exception e) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("exception");
        mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());

        return mav;
    }
}
```

Am I missing any spring dependency??
Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ControllerAdvice` annotation was introduced in Spring Framework 3.2.

Spring 3.0.x is not supported anymore and you should consider upgrading anyway (see [the official wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#actively-supported-generations-32-41-42)).

By the way, you should use only "version agnostic" links in your configuration files, such as `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd`. This can cause issues when upgrading Spring.